# upload image in android studio

Tags: java, php, android-studio, xampp

I'm trying to upload image to xampp server, with android-studio and php
But I will not succeed
Please help me

here is my code(java and php):

java code:
in this codes im trying to select picture from gallery and show a dialog and then uploading image...

```
public final int REQUEST_OPEN_GALLERY = 5;
        ProgressDialog dialog;
        Thread uploadThread;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String id = "";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        public static Handler uploadHandler;
        public static String imageProfile = "";
        
        profile_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                chooseFile();
            }
        });

    }
    private void chooseFile() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_OPEN_GALLERY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_OPEN_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            String[] info = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, info, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(info[0]);
            final String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,filePath,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getContext(), "upload", "Uploading file...");

            uploadThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    uploadFile(filePath);
                }
            });
            uploadThread.start();

        }
    }
    private void uploadFile(String filePath) {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.6/zanborak/sabtenam/upload.php");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            connection.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", filePath);

            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd + "Content-Disposition: form-data;" +
                    " name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\"" + filePath + "\"\r\n\r\n");
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        
            if (connection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                uploadHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Upload Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        imageProfile = "";
                        
                    }
                });

            }

            fileInputStream.close();
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

and php:

in this code im trying move the image to "upload" folder...

```
    <?php
include "connect.php";
$rand=microtime();
$path="upload/".$rand.($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"],$path);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you use [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) library. it a light library to exchange data & media through Http protocol and await the response.

you can see how to add it as a dependency in [official website](https://square.github.io/retrofit/).

you also need to add [Gson serializer](https://github.com/google/gson) dependency in your gradle.

Once done create responsable to get Retrofit object:

```
public class RetrofitApiClient {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.1.6/"; //htt

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .serializeNulls()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    private RetrofitApiClient() {} // So that nobody can create an object with constructor

    public static synchronized Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            int timeOut = 5 * 60;
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .connectTimeout(timeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(timeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(timeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build();

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(client)
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Retrofit turns your HTTP API into a Java interface, so create an interface to handle url for the upload

```
public interface FileService {

    @Multipart
    @POST("/zanborak/sabtenam/upload.php")
    Call<String> UploadImage( 
            @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
}
```

Now you can create a class responsable to push your file to the server and wait for the response.

```
public class ImageUploaderClass {

    //listerner for the task
    public interface OnSuccessfullTask {
        void onSuccess();
        void onFailed(String error);
    }

    public static void uploadImage(String filePath,  OnSuccessfullTask task) {
        try {
            FileService apiInterface = RetrofitApiClient.getClient().create( FileService .class);

            File file = new File(filePath);
            //create RequestBody instance from file
            RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image"), file);

            // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
            MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("uploaded_file", file.getName(), requestFile);

            // finally, execute the request
            Call<String> call = apiInterface.UploadImage(body);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<String> call, @NonNull Response<String> response) {
                    String responseBody = response.body();
                    if (responseBody != null) {
                        if ("ok".equals(responseBody)) {
                            task.onSuccess();
                        } else { 
                            task.onFailed(responseBody);
                        }
                    } else { 
                        task.onFailed(responseBody);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<String> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {
                    task.onFailed(t.getMessage());
                }

            });
        }
        catch (Exception ignored){}
    }

}
```

in your Php returns something to the app in case of success or failure

```
<?php
include "connect.php";
$rand=microtime();
$path="upload/".$rand.($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]);
$r = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"],$path);
if($r){
echo 'ok';
}
else{
echo 'error';
}
?>
```

Lastly you can call **uploadImage** in **ActivityResult** and pass it the file name and the Actions you need in case of success ot failure